# What is the equivalent for this function without the pipe that will work for php 7.4.29?

Tags: php

I have some code in my opencart php code that is written for php 8.0. It contains a pipe symbol. I have used composer to try and update this but it does not clean up the code. The code is in this file. upload\system\library\log.php line 31.

```
    public function write(string|array $message): void {
        $this->message .= date('Y-m-d H:i:s') . ' - ' . print_r($message, true) . "\n";
    }
```

How can I replace this pipe. This is the error that it is throwing.

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '|', expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) in upload\system\library\log.php on line 31
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called a union type and they were explicitly introduced in PHP 8.0 ([RFC](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/union_types_v2)).

As documented there the pre-php8 way of doing this was to used doc block formatting:

```
/**
 * @param string|array $message
 **/
public function write($message): void {
    $this->message .= date('Y-m-d H:i:s') . ' - ' . print_r($message, true) . "\n";
}
```

The major downside here is this doesn't get type checked by the compiler but, it should be picked up by most IDEs correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to retain the type checking, you can do it manually and throw a [TypeError](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.typeerror.php), which is what happens in PHP8+ automatically. If it's not critical, I'd just do what @JonathanWommack said.

```php
public function write($message): void {
    if(!is_array($message) && !is_string($message))
    {
        throw new TypeError(sprintf('Argument #1 ($message) must be of type string or array, %s given', gettype($message));
    }
    
    $this->message .= date('Y-m-d H:i:s') . ' - ' . print_r($message, true) . "\n";
}
```